# How can a render an array that has children in a react native flatlist and also control how it is viewd

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

> > I want to render a nested array in a react-native flatlist how can I
> > achieve that. i also want to be able to view and hide the children of
> > each item that has the parentId as null an example of the list

```
[
  {
    parentId: null,
    postId: 'GZ28tWH3SqoU03tyNTJp',
    timePosted: 1658089714186,
    comment: 'Hello',
    id: 'NZhIfTBVNS15X5yONj0h',
    children: [
      {
        parentId: 'NZhIfTBVNS15X5yONj0h',
        postId: 'GZ28tWH3SqoU03tyNTJp',
        timePosted: 1658089864025,
        comment: 'I am fine',
        id: 'hNjZumHnbG63g1Yg9p5R',
        children: [
          {
            parentId: 'hNjZumHnbG63g1Yg9p5R',
            postId: 'GZ28tWH3SqoU03tyNTJp',
            timePosted: 1658177972422,
            comment: '@ Ebukaa yaaa',
            id: '8Boid6WuphQ9SkG3Eegm',
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        parentId: 'NZhIfTBVNS15X5yONj0h',
        postId: 'GZ28tWH3SqoU03tyNTJp',
        timePosted: 1658177624449,
        comment: 'Okay',
        id: 'ruvwbJA1ezgvEauqPFLa',
        children: [
          {
            parentId: 'ruvwbJA1ezgvEauqPFLa',
            postId: 'GZ28tWH3SqoU03tyNTJp',
            timePosted: 1658177755359,
            comment: '@ Ebukaa hello',
            id: 'nUrGIqN69x57LoSSjoJQ',
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sectionlist which is given in react native.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist